# Composer doesn't autoload packages

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php, autoload

I'm currently developing a framework but I couldn't figure out how am I going to set autoloading. First I created a package with sample class and composer.json. I've autoloaded that sample class by:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "libs/"
    ]
}
```

I've checked /vendor/mypackage/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and confirmed that package's autoloader is working fine. But the problem is I can't reach that package's class from main app unless I directly include that package's autoload.php.

**UPDATE**

/vendor/foo/mypackage/composer.json

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
     "Http\\": "libs/"
   }
}
```

/vendor/foo/mypackage/libs/Request.php

```
namespace Http;
class Request {}
```

Comment: If you come here in 2019, all you need to do is `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by myself. I just had to reinstall package whenever I change pacakge's composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's often better to use `psr-0` or `psr-4` autoloading config. With the classmap, you have to redump the autoloader each time you add a new class or rename one.

You always need to include the Composer autoloader by using `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`. The best place to add such require statement is in your front controller file.

Comment: I use psr-4 for my mvc framework but it didn't work for my composer package. Also I include that /vendor/autoload.php but I can't use MyPackage\SampleClass without including /vendor/mypackage/vendor/autoload.php. Is /vendor/autoload.php not supposed to be include that packages' autoloaders too? Have I to include all package autoloaders one-by-one?

Comment: Why is there a `vendor` directory in the `mypackage` dir? If you require your package with Composer, all dependencies will be installed in the root `vendor/` directory and all autoloading will be set-up in the root `vendor/autoload.php`.

Comment: There is a vendor folder because I used to run dump-autoload command in /vendor/mypackage but later I understood that's not required. I've updated my question. I'm calling my class like this: `new \Http\Request()`. I don't see any mistakes on my code.